# Align an <hr> element inside a flex Container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Does anyone know how to align an `<hr>` element inside a flex-container.  When I do `flex-start` all of the other elements align, apart from the `<hr>`.  I need a solution that doesn't use `position: absolute` on the `<hr>` element because this affects the document flow and causes other issues.

codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/QaPQaW

CSS

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

hr {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 75px;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <h1> Hello </h1>
  <hr>
  <p> Thanks </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there something I can add or adjust, to have my answer accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hr` element has a default margin set, and in Chrome it is set to:

```
-webkit-margin-before: 0.5em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.5em;
-webkit-margin-start: auto;
-webkit-margin-end: auto;
```

And as auto margin's in Flexbox override the `justify-content`/`align-*` properties, you need to remove it, which e.g. `margin: 0;` will, and make the in  this case `align-items: flex-start;` be properly applied.

Stack snippet

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.box {
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

hr {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 75px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin: 0;                           /* added  */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <hr>
  <p>Thanks</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `hr` to

```
background: white;
height: 3px;
width: 75px;
margin-left: 0;
```